# Sudoers command with wildcard arguments doesn't match 0-length arguments

Tags: linux, sudo, sudoers

I need to allow a set of users to run, as a different user, a command with the following structure:

```
command [args] subcommand [subargs]
```

both args and subargs should be optional.
I this tries whitelisting the following in sudoers:

```
/path/to/command * subcommand *
```

However, this only works if both args and subargs are specified.

The [documentation](https://www.sudo.ws/man/1.8.15/sudoers.man.html#Wildcards) says:

> " * " Matches any set of zero or more characters (including white space).

I hope this is clear. Any help is much appreciated.

(P.S. I am aware of the security risk that is that users could run a different subcommand if they have the name of subcommand somewhere else in the arguments. This is an accepted risk, but mitigation is still welcome.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to achieve this is to eliminate the spaces between the wildcards and the subcommand:

```
/path/to/command *subcommand*
```